# Issue in reading a repeat event

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, calendar, jsr75

I am working on a calendar application, where I am trying to read if a event is recurring. I am able to read the recurring event value on for the day when the recurring event was created.

Suppose I have created a events "xyz" on 24th apr, occurs daily (frequency) and ends on 26th April. So here in my app I can see only the event on 24th, I am not getting any event present on 25th and 26th these events are repeated.

I am using the following snippet to get all the events:

```
EventList eventList = null;
            eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
                    PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
```

This not returning the dates where events are repeated. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to `RepeatRule` class and `getRepeat`, `setRepeat` methods in `Event` class

Comment: ya i have used the repeatRule api,the problem is in getting event list for the repeated events,if the event is repeated on some day,the event is not reteived using PIM api @Eugen Martynov

Comment: Sorry don't have too much experience with calendar events. So you need to iterate over all events and determine by start date and repeat rule if it happens today. Correct?

Comment: to iterate over the evetns the pim api should return me the repeated event,its not returning that event. @Eugen Martynov